# Not receiving notifications when getting Likes on a comment on a page's post on Facebook

Tags: facebook

When I receive *Likes* on my comment that I posted on the post of a page, I don't receive notifications. Where can I change these settings?

Answer (score 2):

It would be default set as On,you can review by going to Settings -> Notification.

In that option "Activity that involves youView" which include You'll always get notifications about activity that involves you, like when someone tags you in a photo or comments on your post is set as On.Please try login with facebook in web and check whether you are getting notification correctly.

Comment: It is turned on but I never get notifications of it. Sometimes I comment on a post (of a page not a person) and I get a lot of likes but I don't get notifications of it.

Comment: My experience: FB sent me notifications for each like until there were 5 likes. then it stopped. I randomly checked my comment, there were 7 likes but no notification; yesterday I got another notification about the 10th like; today it's 11 and still no notification.
My conclusion is: FB stops/decreases bothering you as the no. of likes increases. There logic seems: each time for 1-5, then on 10th, then maybe on 20th or 100th I don't know. I came here to find and answer myself, coz I don't always get that much likes; I wanted somehow to enable the notification for each like, I'd feel happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Been experiencing that problem for months too and no Google answer has ever helped me. I tried fixing it myself as of the moment and I'm glad it worked.

Go to Settings > Notifications > More Activity About You > and you'll see this.

"These are notifications for posts to your timeline, Likes and other Reactions to your posts, and more."

Turn on Allow Notifications on Facebook. Then viola!